# Please I need help writing a test class for this scheduled class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

```java
public with sharing class Repeating_Scheduler implements Schedulable{

    private final String JOB_NAME = 'PriceBookEntryHandler Job';
    private final Integer ONE_MINUTE = 1;
    
    private void execute(SchedulableContext cont){
       new PriceBookEntryHandler().queryAndCreateNotifier();
        findAndAbortJob(cont);
    }
    
    private void findAndAbortJob(SchedulableContext cont){
        if (cont == null){
            return;
        }
        
        List<CronJobDetail> cronDetail = [SELECT Id FROM CronJobDetail WHERE Name= :JOB_NAME LIMIT 1];
        
        if (cronDetail.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
         
        List<CronTrigger> cronTriggers = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetailId = :cronDetail[0].Id];
        
        if(cronTriggers.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        
        try{
            //Aborts the job current setup for this scheduled class
            System.abortJob(cronTriggers[0].Id);
            rescheduleJob();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.debug('This was the error ::: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
/*
* @description Reschedules this job for one minute in the future.
*/
    private void rescheduleJob(){
        Datetime sysTime = System.now().addMinutes(ONE_MINUTE);
        String cronExpression = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
        System.schedule(JOB_NAME, cronExpression, new Repeating_Scheduler());
    }
}
```

// BELOW IS THE REFERENCED CLASS

```java
public class PriceBookEntryHandler {
    public void queryAndCreateNotifier(){
        List<Notifier__c> notif = new List<Notifier__c>();
        Set<Id> inActivePbeIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Notifier__c> updatedNotifiers = new List<Notifier__c>();
        
        List<PriceBookEntry> pbEntries = [SELECT  Id,
                                          Pricebook2Id,
                                          LastModifiedBy.Name,
                                          CreatedDate,
                                          IsActive,
                                          Product2.Name
                                          FROM PriceBookEntry 
                                          WHERE SystemModStamp >:Datetime.now().addMinutes(-1)
                                          AND IsActive = True];
        
        List<PriceBookEntry> inActivePbEntries = [SELECT  Id,
                                                  Pricebook2Id,
                                                  LastModifiedBy.Name,
                                                  CreatedDate,
                                                  IsActive,
                                                  Product2.Name
                                                  FROM PriceBookEntry 
                                                  WHERE SystemModStamp >:Datetime.now().addMinutes(-1)
                                                  AND IsActive = false];
        
        if(!pbEntries.isEmpty()){
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe: pbEntries){
                Notifier__c n = New Notifier__c();
                if(n.Price_book_Entry_Id__c != pbe.Id){
                    n.Modified_Price_Book__c = pbe.Pricebook2Id;
                    n.Price_book_Entry_Id__c = pbe.Id;
                    n.PBE_Item__c            = pbe.Product2.Name;
                    n.IsInsert__c            = true;
                    n.Modified_By__c         = pbe.LastModifiedBy.Name; 
                    notif.add(n); 
                    system.debug('New pricebook entry Id ::: ' + n.Price_book_Entry_Id__c);
                    system.debug('Inserted by ::: ' + n.Modified_By__c);
                } 
            }
            
            Insert notif;
        }
        if(!inActivePbEntries.isEmpty()){
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe : inActivePbEntries){
                inActivePbeIdSet.add(pbe.Id);
                System.debug('inActivePbEntries: ' + inActivePbEntries);
            }
            
        }
        
        List<Notifier__c> notifiersToUpdate = [SELECT Id, PBE_Item__c, Modified_By__c, Price_book_Entry_Id__c FROM Notifier__c WHERE Price_book_Entry_Id__c IN : inActivePbeIdSet AND IsInsert__c = true];
        
        if(!notifiersToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            System.debug('notifiersToUpdate: ' + notifiersToUpdate);
            for(Notifier__c nf: notifiersToUpdate){
                nf.IsChanged__c = True;
                nf.IsInsert__c  = False;
                nf.PBE_Item__c  = nf.PBE_Item__c;
                nf.Modified_By__c = UserInfo.getName();
                updatedNotifiers.add(nf);
                system.debug('Modified pricebook entry Id ::: ' + nf.Price_book_Entry_Id__c);
                system.debug('Modified by ::: ' + nf.Modified_By__c);
            }
            Update updatedNotifiers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to add the test class you've written so far. There's not much special about testing schedulable apex compared to testing "normal" classes. If your methods were `public`, you could simply call them directly. Otherwise, scheduling them and proper use of `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`  will cause async code to be run synchronously within the context of the test method.

Comment: I find that unit testing code that is selecting from CronTrigger is best handled by wrapping the SOQL into a selector object and then at unit test time, dependency inject a mock selector that returns various CronTrigger objects.